# why is my rigid body (buildings) moving so randomly?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

As you can see from the gif, the buildings when they break, instead of crumbling they seem to flail around. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: maybe a problem of Sensitivity > Collision Margin, or apply the scale?

Comment: pls provide blend file (maybe by dropbox because blend-exchange seems to have problems rn)